# Zooming Image with another Image Absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have added a basic jQuery zoom plug-in to a large image (a map) and I'd like to add several markers to it, but I am unsure how to attach them to a certain coordinate that zooms with the plug-in and means that the marker is in the same position.

The jQuery plug-in is [Wheel Zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/) and my code so far is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="map-container">
    <div id="main-markers"><img src="marker1.png" /></div>
        <img id="map" class='map' src='Final/WorldMap2.jpg' width='1280' height='1028'/>
    </div>
    <script src="wheelzoom.js"></script>
    <script>
        wheelzoom(document.querySelector('img.map'));
    </script>
</body>
```